# Pandas Dataframe subtraction of floats values produces different values from expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database

I have 2 columns/Series in a Dataframe (df) that looks like the following:

```
0    0.657012
1    0.338250
2    0.652448
Name: prob1, dtype: float64

0    0.657012
1    0.338249
2    0.652448
Name: prob2, dtype: float64
```

When I perform the following substraction operation:

```
df['diff'] = df.prob1 - df.prob2
```

I got incorrect results which are different from expected as in the following:

```
0    2.384000e-07
1    1.192000e-07
2    2.384000e-07
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Why is that ?

Many thanks and appreciations.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the dtype is in `float` and the resultant values are very small and therefore scientific notations are used.
You can use the round function to get the required output.

```
df['result'] = (df.prob1 - df1.prob2).apply(round,1)
```

Or you can manipulate the pandas option to display the result in float format and not in scientific notation -

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)
df['result'] = df.prob1 - df1.prob2

# or

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
```

One more alternative is to use apply -

```
df['diff'] = df.prob1 - df.prob2
df['diff'].apply(lambda x: '%.5f' % x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. even though the results are small, I still want to use the results for plotting later. If round up to 8, I got zeros. The set_option is only effect when you display the value but the actual values in memories isn't change ? I tried the alternative, it is says no axis argument for lambda. How can I resolve this, many thanks.

Comment: Plotting will work. Round off will just strip off the data to display it in a required format. And remove the axis args then it'll work

Comment: I tried plotting after applying lambda function, it is not consistent with the values in the resulting operation. For example. I got value of 2 which is not possible giving the number of differences are very small and should go to 2?

Comment: Why not multiply this data with some large number like 100000 and then take the diff?

Comment: Because I want to have an interval between 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

As per [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html), default precision for displaying float values is 6 (i.e. printing a DataFrame with floats will display 6 values after the decimal).

This does not change the stored value in the DataFrame, just what is displayed when printing it out. Therefore, when printing the DataFrames, it looks like values should be identical, but the mathematical operations are performed on the stored values (different from what you see), thus result seems inconsistent.

I suggest printing a couple of individual values (i.e. indexing both column and index to access a single value), and compare to what you see when you print the entire DataFrame/Series. You should see the whole value when printing it individualy, and these values should be consistent with the results you get from mathematical operations.

Alternatively, you could change display.precision via:

```
pd.set_option('precision', n)
```

where `n` is the number of digits after the decimal to be displayed (default 6)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the decimal to 10 places since diff is very small, please modify it as per need basis.

```
df['diff'] = np.round(df.prob1 - df.prob2, decimals=10) # OR
df['diff'] = df.prob1.sub(df.prob2).round(10)
```

**Output**

```
    prob1       prob2       diff
0   0.657012    0.657012    0.000000
1   0.338250    0.338249    0.000001
2   0.652448    0.652448    0.000000
```